# UWP DataGrid - Individual Cell Based Selection?

Tags: c#, uwp

By default, when selecting values in a UWP DataGrid the entire row is selected/highlighted. On top of this, you are unable to click and drag to select multiple cells. Pressing CTRL+LClick or Shift+LClick will add rows to the selection, but even this does not allow for multiple *cells* to be selected.

Is there a way to allow the user to select individual cells? Furthermore, is there a way to allow for a click and drag to select multiple cells within the created rectangle?

Comment: Do you have any reproduceable code? An example is needed to clearly understand what you are trying to achieve when you state "select individual cells."

Answer (score 0):

> UWP DataGrid - Individual Cell Based Selection?

I have to say currently there is no such `SelectionUnit` api that use to select multiple individual cell,

UWP `DataGrid` selection model only contains extended and single. It could only use to select entire row. if you want to this feature, I'd suggest you submit a feedback/feature request about this API/feature in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**->**API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.